# Using pandas dataframe to write values to a new csv file error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, series

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

basefileread = pd.read_csv('50.csv', encoding='latin-1')
basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[basefileread['Customer'].str.contains("Lam Dep", na=False), 'Jul-18\nQty']

basefilevalue.to_csv('data.csv', sep='\t')

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(basefilevalue)
```

So I am running this code to take these specific values out of one csv file, and wish to print it to another. I am however receiving this error:

```
csv.Error: iterable expected, not float
```

The answer posted below helps run my code without error, however no data is printing to my csv file. Is this an issue with my code or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.writer.writerows` accepts an *iterable of iterables*, while `writerow` accepts an *iterable*.

You are feeding a series of floats, which would only work with `writerow` and only if you wish all values to be on the first line. Therefore, you can amend to:

```
list_of_lists = [[i] for i in basefilevalue.values]
writer.writerows(list_of_lists)
```

This will write each element of the series `basefilevalue` on a separate line.

However, it's unclear why you are resorting to the `csv` module when, as in your existing code, you can use [`pd.Series.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html).

Comment: thank you, this helped my code run without errors. However I am still unsure why data is not printing to my csv file and am unsure if it has to do with my code, or I am not executing command on the command prompt correctly.